# uniapp write android plugin has exception on invoke jsMethod

Tags: uniapp

2024-02-17 10:15:41.347 5042-5084/com.aiku.offline E/testMoudle: testAdd: {"name":"张三","age":20}
2024-02-17 10:15:41.350 5042-5084/com.aiku.offline E/weex: reportJSException >>>> instanceId:2, exception function:**WEEX_CALL_JAVASCRIPT**, exception:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at  (pages/index/index.js.nvue:1:2313)
2024-02-17 10:15:41.350 5042-5084/com.aiku.offline E/weex: onJSException -2013,Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at  (pages/index/index.js.nvue:1:2313)
2024-02-17 10:15:41.350 5042-5084/com.aiku.offline E/weex: commitCriticalExceptionRT :WX_ERR_JS_EXECUTEexceptionJavaScript execute error!Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at  (pages/index/index.js.nvue:1:2313)

```
@UniJSMethod(uiThread = false)
public void testAdd(JSONObject options, UniJSCallback callback){
    // 入参
    Log.e(TAG, "testAdd: " + options );
    int sum = add(1, 2);
    if(callback != null) {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("code", "success");
        data.put("sum", sum);
        callback.invoke(data);
    }
}
```

```
// 测试按钮
            testHandle(){
                const data = {
                    name: "张三",
                    age: 20
                }
                testMoudle.testAdd(JSON.stringify(data), res => {
                    console.log("【回调结果】", res);
                    uni.showToast({
                        icon:"none",
                        title: JSON.parse(res)
                    });
                })
            },
```

Comment: is not "JSON.parse(res)", really answer is "JSON.stringify(res)". because callback result not is JSON but a String